# How can we show that $Q =B-Ce^{-kt}$ is a solution of $\frac{dQ}{dt} = k(B-Q)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I appreciate your time and any help in advance, as I'm teaching myself calculus and am pretty much on my own.

A text I'm working from asks us to show that $Q = B-Ce^{-kt}$ (the learning curve) is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{dQ}{dt} = k(B-Q)$.

I believe the text wants us to differentiate the right side $(B-Ce^{-kt})$ in order to end up with $k(B-Q)$.

If so, I don't know how $k(B-Q)$ is derived, and would like to know.

**More importantly, if I'm only allowed one question**:

I took an opposite approach, and tried to 'solve' the differential equation $dQ/dt = k(B-Q)$,
in order to end up with the general equation: $B-Ce^{-kt}$.

I'd like to know if I erred (which is probable) and how.

I also have a question about the minus sign in $e^{-kt}$ (although it seems intuitive.)  Here's my work:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = K(B-Q)$$

Separating the variables:

$$\frac{1}{B-Q} dQ = Kdt$$

Integrating:

$$\ln |B-Q| = -Kt + C$$

(I know the minus sign in front of the $K$ term is necessary in order to make this work, but what  necessitates it, mathematically?)

Taking exponents:

$$|B-Q| = e^{-kt + C} = e^C \cdot e^{-kt} = Ce^{-kt}$$

I believe I can drop the absolute value sign on the left now, as $C$ can be of any sign:

$$B-Q = Ce^{-kt}$$

$$-Q = Ce^{-kt}-B$$

$$Q = B-Ce^{-kt}$$

Is that  correct? And why the minus sign?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @KennyWong You forgot to add `{ }` in the exponentials

Comment: @VictorJaroslaw Please don't use $k$ and $K$ indistinctly.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate $Q$ with respect to $t$

$\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = C k e^{-kt} $

But $ C e^{-k t} = B - Q $

Therefore,

$\dfrac{dQ}{dt} = k (B - Q ) $

Answer (score 0):

The reason for minus sign is due to LHS:

$$\int \frac{dQ}{B-Q} = -\int \frac{dQ}{Q-B} = - \ln(Q-B) = Kt+C$$

Hence, $$ln(Q-B) = -Kt+C'$$

Comment: Does the switch from (B-Q) to -(Q-B) have to do with the the fact that I'm integrating with respect to Q, not B, or some other reason? Thx

Comment: you are correct. $\int \frac{dy}{y} = \ln(y)$. So $\int \frac{dQ}{B-Q} = \int -\frac{d(B-Q)}{B-Q} = -\ln(B-Q)$. Note that $d(B-Q) = dB - dQ = -dQ$ since $B$ is a constant and $Q$ is a variable.